# 'truffle unbox react' unboxing failed

Tags: node.js, truffle

after successfully installing truffle, when I want to create a react via truffle it shows error...

```
PS C:\Users\devan\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder> truffle unbox react

Starting unbox...
=================

√ Preparing to download box
× Downloading
Unbox failed!
× Downloading
Unbox failed!
RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND raw.githubusercontent.com
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\devan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:14:1)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\Users\devan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:87:1)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\devan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:1)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\devan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\request\request.js:185:1)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\devan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\request\request.js:881:1)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Truffle v5.1.64 (core: 5.1.64)
Node v18.13.0
```

Why the unboxing failed??

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, the solution is to downgrade the node and truffle versions.

But I have a solution where we don't have to downgrade the node version and `truffle-box react` will be up and running. We will go old school.

- **Step 1** -  Clone the truffle-box/react-box repo. from [here](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/)

> Now we have to do two major things, first one is to `compile` & `migrate` the smart contracts and the next is to install the `npm` dependencies (because `npm module` doesn't go in a repo. instead `package.json` have all the dependencies required written.)

- **Step 2** -  Use the command `cd truffle` to go inside the truffle folder in your project structure through the command line(Terminal). Now run **`truffle develop`**, and after that run **`compile`** and **`migrate`** one by one, after all these three commands are successfully executed, exit the terminal.
- **Step 3** - Type `cd ..` to get out of the truffle folder and use `cd client` to enter inside the `client` folder, now run **`npm install`**.
- **Step 4** - All done , use command **`npm start`** inside the client folder, your truffle-box + react is configured.

[Image showing localhost 8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkQpU.png)

Hope it helps.